# Can we ask code specific questions?

Tags: discussion

Example: Can I ask a question about a particular input tag that is used in a specific code (let's say `VASP`) which might end up into an insight in the overall theory that particular code is based on. For instance, if I ask about charge density mixing related tags in `VASP` then the answers might give information about both, those particular tags and the topic of charge density mixing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You are encouraged to ask code specific questions here. The long term goal of our community is to become **the hub** for all matter modelling related queries. For more details check out this [answer](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/39/88)

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely! I see no reason why not, and that's part of the purpose of this site :)

Here's my answers to some very related questions:

- https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/149/5
- https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/39/5